Inkscape bug when convertig stroke to path
I am using Debian 12 and have installed Inkscape both using the Debian repository (version 1.2.2) and Flatpak (version 1.3.2).
I am using Inkscape to create a font by transforming the letters from another font. I want to carve out part of the original characters to obtain the new characters.
In order to do that, for each character I create a copy of it, set the filling to empty and the stroke to 3pt, and then choose "Stroke to path". (I do not know if this is the best method to obtain what I want...) When I do this, Inkscape transforms the stroke to path in a faulty way for most of the characters, mainly around corners. Using Inkscape v1.2.2 gives a better result than v1.3.2, but still a buggy one.
I hope the attached image makes it easy to understand what I mean. The first pair of letters (BO) are the original letters, the second are the original letter with no filling and stroke of 3pt, and the third is the application of "Stroke to path" to the second pair. I have used the red circles to emphasize the main problems.

Why is this happening? And how can I solve it?

Yes, there's a bug in Inkscape 1.3.2 where glitches can appear when converting stroke to path depending on the path direction. Path direction shouldn't affect stroke to path. I believe it's fixed in the 1.4 beta.
However, there is a work around for 1.3.2 if you don't want to install the beta (which can be unstable).

Add a thick stroke to the paths as normal

Do Path > Break apart. This will separate all the internal counters of the letters as separate paths

Select the counters (the inner parts of the letters) and do Path > Reverse to reverse their direction

Select all, and do Path > Stroke to path

Do Path > Union


An example: top shows the paths after union, and below is the finished result


This indeed helps, but I still get some glitches on the sharp corners, for instance the top left and bottom left inner corners of the letter B. Any idea of how to fix this?

I broke the paths on the sharper nodes and it seems to help...

@PedroG.Mattos I don't get any glitches after these steps, as you can see from my screenshot. Maybe it's the font?  What font did you use? I used Noto Serif Bold.

I used both Latin Modern and Stix Two

I just tested with Noto Serif Bold and I also get glitches

@PedroG.Mattos - Try enlarging the letters first.  I did this using 200pt text. Here's my SVG if you want to check it.

This worked! I was just assuming size didn't matter since it is vector graphics...

@PedroG.Mattos Size does matter because of possible accuracy problems. Since vectors are actually stored as numbers, and smaller numbers will be rounded to a set number of decimal places during calculations, they just won't be so accurate at smaller scales. Working at a larger scale will allow for more accuracy in calculations.
